# Calculate first number in a list like BlackJack card game

Tags: python

I am just a newbie to python and my teacher tell me to create BlackJack game.And i stuck at the stage is count the total number of card.Here is what i got now, i need general solution for this one so i create a new python for this stage(just for testing)

```
list=["20","10","30"]
###I want to check first character of the number and add it together so i do this.

i = 0
while i < len(list):
      first_letter=list[i][0]
      i=i+1
      second_letter=list[i][0]
      total = first_letter+second_letter
      print(total)
####This is just an example for testing.
```

And when i run the code it work somehow but also have this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\PYTHON BLACKJACK\00.py", line 9, in <module>

    second_letter=int(movie[i][0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

i can not understand this one. can someone help me with this???

Comment: Think of what would happen when `i` is `len(list) - 1` & then you do `i += 1`. After that you try to access `list[i]`

Comment: Is the error from the same version of the code as listed in your question? I don't see `second_letter=int(movie[i][0])` anywhere in your code listing, but that's what the error message says where the problem occurred.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the loop? What do the strings in your list mean, and how do they help you play blackjack?

Comment: like if i got 5D and KD it should be 15 in total

Comment: Python knows nothing about card values in Black Jack, so you'd have explicitly tell it to convert `"K"` (and other face cards) to `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna try and help you while changing as little to your code as possible.

```
 `first_letter=list[i][0]
  i=i+1
  second_letter=list[i][0]`
```

Look closely what you are doing there. `list[i]` takes the first element of the list: `"20"`. `[0]` takes the first character of that element, so: `"2"`. What you want to do is get the second character of the string. When you change your i variable, you are changing the element you are getting from the list, not the character. What you should do is:

```
first_letter = list[i][0]
second_letter = list[i][1]
i += 1
```

Where `i =+= 1` makes sure you switch to your next item in the list for the next 'loop'.

Besides that, when you try and add characters, they will not 'add up'. If you want to numerically add the first_letter to the second_letter, you should do this:

```
print(int(first_letter) + int(second_letter)
```

Here `int()` converts the character to an integer, which can be added together.

And finally, note that this method will only work when you have one digit numbers. If you want to do this with numbers regardless of their size, you should probably use a list in a list. f.e.:

```
items = [[3,0],[2,0],[1,0]]
```

Your loop would work just fine with the edited code, and you wouldn't need to use `int()`.

Comment: It depends how you want to do it, For J,Q,K you could just add their numerical values to your list instead of their letters, which then would work fine. But if you would like to have a letter in your list, you could check what your letter is before adding them together. You should do this with if/else statements. if first_letter == "J": do something. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enumerate()` and a for loop. Also it's best to not override python builtin functions like `list()`

```py
list = ["20", "10", "30"]
###I want to check first character of the number and add it together so i do this.

for i, item in enumerate(list):
      first_letter = int(item[0])
      second_letter = int(item[1])
      total = first_letter + second_letter
      print(total)
```

Comment: well im just a new to python and maybe my teacher wont allow to use that . Anyway thank you for your help

Comment: (maybe a bit of advertising here) if you want to try a functioning blackjack game you can reach me on discord

Comment: yeah what is your discord??

Answer (score 0):

When you want to process all the elements of a list it is (arguably) considered more *pythonic* to iterate using a `for` statement rather than a `while` loop, like this:

```py
numbers = ["20", "10", "30"]

total = 0
for number in numbers:
    first, second = number
    total += int(first) + int(second)
print(total)
```

Please be aware that all the strings in `numbers` must have exactly two characters. Otherwise this code will fail.

This one-liner is more robust as the strings in `numbers` can have any number of digits:

```py
total = sum(sum(int(digit) for digit in number) for number in numbers)
```

The solution above can be made a bit less verbose by using the built-in function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
total = sum(sum(map(int, number)) for number in numbers)
```

Comment: that is very helpful but what if i has many number and i want to add it all together?

Comment: Thank you @das-g for spotting this. I forgot converting the digits to int. Edited my answer and the code is now working